# Can't get this clip path to work no matter what

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to run this small gif inside an SVG animation on my localhost, I've compiled the scss into css, but still, nothing is visible.

Here's the code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Define our SVG clip path -->
<svg width='0' height='0'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cp" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0.500, 0.945 L0.994, 0.090 L0.006, 0.090 L0.500, 0.945 L0.500, 0.650 L0.262, 0.238 L0.738, 0.237 L0.500, 0.650z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<!-- The actual elements we're using -->
<div class="triangle first"></div>
<div class="triangle second"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #B8BEB4;
  background: radial-gradient(#B8BEB4, #71685F);
  background-size: cover; }

.triangle {
  clip-path: url(#cp);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
  max-width: 75vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; }

.first {
  background-color: #C5075C;
  background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/pE6GG0V2JCKUo/giphy.gif");
  transform: translateX(-65%) translateY(-50%); }

.second {
  background-color: #03B897;
  background-image: url("https://media1.giphy.com/media/fLg3MEWdgH5Ti/200.gif");
  transform: translateX(-35%) translateY(-50%);
  opacity: 0.8; }
```

See the Pen [Reverse clip path with blend modes](https://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/mVEwje/) by Zach Saucier ([@Zeaklous](https://codepen.io/Zeaklous)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: it's working fine on the snippet here using your code

Comment: @Temani I did but I linked it in the html, updating my full html here 1 second.

Comment: CSS inside the HTML the SVG is visible but the gif is not playing. I downloaded the gif put it in the directory instead of url and it plays. Why can't it read the url and why does it not link the .css file???

Comment: ok, it's now working with the url links too, and style in html document, Thank you Temani! I still don't see why #cp cannot be recognized? the svg has the id.

Comment: ok, I will try it as external doc, how is the svg doc styled? html tags?

Comment: first try to correct the typo like mentionned by Bizarre, maybe it has do here

Comment: but Bizarre is me... which typo? sorry?

Comment: Oh sorry i mean QZ Support :) answer below

Comment: Worked! thank you, sry for all that for a typo !

Comment: good, but i though you CSS was working and you face issue with only the svg

Comment: originally I was getting a blank page when running from localhost, then svg worked but not the gif from url...

Comment: at the moment somehow I can run from localhost both on Chrome and Firefox without issues but the original codepen link does not run the gif on Chrome but works fine on firefox. probably cached data issue?

Comment: maybe a cache issue

Comment: Alright, well, not a big deal, thank you Temani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, this works fine if the CSS is placed directly inside the HTML.

Turns out this is a simple typo.  Please change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/css" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif with which browser do you experience different behavior between `<link>` CSS and embedded CSS?  Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: I can see... it's a typo in the link tag.  Editing answer.

Comment: @Bizarre if you correct this typo you see the svg ? by the way, are the other style applied ?

Comment: The page is blank with `stylesheet/css`.  The page works as expected (svg overlay, animated gif) if corrected to `stylesheet`.

Comment: Thanks QZ, that was it.